# STL container for combining multiple very large raster data files in C++

Tags: c++, gis, raster

I am working on a piece of code that need to do something very similar to the combine function in ArcGIS in C/C++. See: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Combining%20multiple%20rasters

The C++ code will read in multiple very large raster data files (2GB+) in chunks, find unique combinations and output to a single map. For example, if there were 3 maps and <1,3,5> existed, respectfully, in the first cell of the three maps then I want all subsequent instances of <1,3,5> to have the same key in the final output map.

What STL containers should I be using to store the maps? Reading in the files in chunks certainly adds more complexity of the project. The algorithm needs to be very fast so I cannot use vectors which have a O(n) complexity for searching. Currently, I'm thinking of using a unsorted_map of unsorted_multimaps but I am not sure if this is correct and if I am going to get the performance I need.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, std::map or std::unordered_map is correct choice. unordered_map is faster and more compact if you don't need order. If you need something even faster, you can replace it with [other map implementation](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/comparison-of-hash-table-libraries/).

Use something compact for the key, something like std::tuple or std::array.

Comment: Usually when people find exactly what they were looking for - they accept the answer or at least rate it up.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the site. I labeled it as the correct answer! I will implement the code with tuples as the key for an unordered map similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408934/using-a-stdtuple-as-key-for-stdunordered-map. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.