# Using tuple in unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map, stdtuple

I want to use tuple consisting of `int`,`char`,`char` in my `unordered_map`. I am doing like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

tuple <int,char,char> kk;
unordered_map<kk,int> map;

int main()
{
    map[1,"c","b"]=23;
    return 0;
}
```

but this gives me following errors:

```
map.cpp:9:21: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list     for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Hash, class _Pred, class _Alloc> class    std::unordered_map’
map.cpp:9:21: error:   expected a type, got ‘kk’
map.cpp:9:21: error: template argument 3 is invalid
map.cpp:9:21: error: template argument 4 is invalid
map.cpp:9:21: error: template argument 5 is invalid
map.cpp:9:26: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
map.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
map.cpp:14:16: error: assignment of read-only location ‘"b"[map]’
```

What I am doing wrong in this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The template arguments for an unordered_map looks like this:

```
template<

    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

`std::hash` is [not specialized for tuples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) (scroll down to Standard specializations for library types). Therefore you need to provide your own, something like this:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, char, char> key_t;

struct key_hash : public std::unary_function<key_t, std::size_t>
{
 std::size_t operator()(const key_t& k) const
 {
   return std::get<0>(k) ^ std::get<1>(k) ^ std::get<2>(k);
 }
};
// ..snip..
typedef std::unordered_map<const key_t,data,key_hash,key_equal> map_t;
//                                             ^ this is our custom hash
```

And finally, as Benjamin Lindley answer already addresses, you need to use `std::make_tuple`:

```
// d is data
m[std::make_tuple(1, 'a', 'b')] = d;
auto itr = m.find(std::make_tuple(1, 'a', 'b'));
```

The code was grabbed from [Using a std::tuple as key for std::unordered_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408934/using-a-stdtuple-as-key-for-stdunordered-map) and here is the [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dede823b40af4662).

Comment: Can you please explain how you have defined key_hash? or what is being done inside key_hash?

Comment: @Zara See the link for more information. `key_hash` is defined above. Later, we use it as one of the template arguments (where unordered_map requires a Hash).

Comment: XOR'ing the fields is a terrible hash function. Please do not use this code as-is. See e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3876.pdf

Answer (score 15):

First error:

```
map.cpp:9:21: error:   expected a type, got ‘kk’
```

As the error clearly says, the template parameter needs to be a type. `kk` is not a type, it is an object. Perhaps you meant to make it a typedef?

```
typedef tuple <int,char,char> kk;
unordered_map<kk,int> map;
```

Second error:

```
map[1,"c","b"]=23;
```

Two problems here. First, putting commas between values does not make a tuple out of them.  You need to be explicit about it, either calling the constructor of your tuple type, or using a function which returns a tuple (e.g. `std::make_tuple`). Second, your tuple is expecting chars (`'c','b'`), not strings (`"c","b"`).

```
map[std::make_tuple(1,'c','b')] = 23;
```

Answer (score 13):

As pointed out, std::hash is not specialized for tuples. However, if your tuple consists of standard hashable types like string and int, the following code from [generic-hash-for-tuples-in-unordered-map-unordered-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110301/generic-hash-for-tuples-in-unordered-map-unordered-set) will automatically add such support in c++11.

Just paste the code in a header file and include it whenever needed:

```
#include <tuple>
// function has to live in the std namespace 
// so that it is picked up by argument-dependent name lookup (ADL).
namespace std{
    namespace
    {

        // Code from boost
        // Reciprocal of the golden ratio helps spread entropy
        //     and handles duplicates.
        // See Mike Seymour in magic-numbers-in-boosthash-combine:
        //     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780

        template <class T>
        inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, T const& v)
        {
            seed ^= hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        }

        // Recursive template code derived from Matthieu M.
        template <class Tuple, size_t Index = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>
        struct HashValueImpl
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            HashValueImpl<Tuple, Index-1>::apply(seed, tuple);
            hash_combine(seed, get<Index>(tuple));
          }
        };

        template <class Tuple>
        struct HashValueImpl<Tuple,0>
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            hash_combine(seed, get<0>(tuple));
          }
        };
    }

    template <typename ... TT>
    struct hash<std::tuple<TT...>> 
    {
        size_t
        operator()(std::tuple<TT...> const& tt) const
        {                                              
            size_t seed = 0;                             
            HashValueImpl<std::tuple<TT...> >::apply(seed, tt);    
            return seed;                                 
        }                                              

    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a requirement of map instead of unordered map:
key was 3-tuple and
value was a 4-tuple

seeing all answers, I was about to change to pairs

but, below worked for me:

```
// declare a map called map1
map <
  tuple<short, short, short>,
  tuple<short, short, short, short>
> map1;

// insert an element into map1
map1[make_tuple(1, 1, 1)] = make_tuple(0, 0, 1, 1);

// this also worked
map1[{1, 1, 1}] = { 0, 0, 1, 1 };
```

I am using visual studio community 2015 ide

Comment: map<T> works because it doesn't require the key type to be hashable.

Answer (score 3):

For those using `boost` they can just reroute hashing to boost's implementation using this

```
#include "boost/functional/hash.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>


using Key = std::tuple<int, char, char>;

struct KeyHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Key & key) const
    {
        return boost::hash_value(key);
    }
};

using Map = std::unordered_map<Key, int, KeyHash>;

int main()
{
    Map map;
    map[1,'c','b'] = 23;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way the functional hash has moved. I am not sure when, but in boost 1.72 it is in ``#include <boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp>`` I am not sure why the boost hash function for a tuple is not documented somewhere. Thanks again for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to use tuple as a key for an unordered_map without using a hash specialization:

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

string fToStr(unordered_map<double,int>& dToI,float x)
{
   static int keyVal=0;
   stringstream ss;
   auto iter = dToI.find(x);
   if(iter == dToI.end()) {
      dToI[x]=++keyVal;
      ss << keyVal;
   } else {
      ss <<  iter->second;
   }
   return ss.str();
}

typedef tuple<int,char,char> TICC;
const char ReservedChar=',';
string getKey(TICC& t)
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << get<0>(t) << ReservedChar << get<1>(t) << ReservedChar << get<2>(t);
   return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
   unordered_map< string,TICC > tupleMp;
   vector<TICC> ticc={make_tuple(1, 'a', 'b'),make_tuple(1, 'b', 'c'),make_tuple(2, 'a', 'b')};
   for(auto t : ticc)
      tupleMp[getKey(t)]=t;

   for(auto t : ticc) {
      string key = getKey(t);
      auto val = tupleMp[key];
      cout << "tupleMp[" << key << "]={" << get<0>(val) << "," << get<1>(val) <<  ","<< get<2>(val) << "} ";
   }
   cout << endl;

   //for float tuple elements use a second float to int key map 
   unordered_map< double,int > dToI;
   vector<float> v{1.234,1.234001,1.234001};
   cout << "\nfloat keys: ";
   for(float f : v)
      cout <<  setprecision(7) << f << "=" << fToStr(dToI,f) << " ";
   cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
tupleMp[1,a,b]={1,a,b} tupleMp[1,b,c]={1,b,c} tupleMp[2,a,b]={2,a,b}

float keys: 1.234=1 1.234001=2 1.234001=2
```

Comment: white space is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110301/generic-hash-for-tuples-in-unordered-map-unordered-set) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094790/how-to-get-hash-code-of-a-string-in-c) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780/magic-number-in-boosthash-combine) I ended up with this. It uses an efficient hash combination algorithm and doesn't specialize things in the `std` namespace. You'll need to do some more work if you want this code to work for any tuple of hashable elements in general.

This works in C++11 and above. In C++03 you can use `boost::hash` instead of `std::hash`.

```cpp
typedef tuple<int, char, char> MyTuple;

// define a hash function for this tuple
struct KeyHash : public std::unary_function<MyTuple, std::size_t> {
    std::size_t operator()(const MyTuple& k) const {
        // the magic operation below makes collisions less likely than just the standard XOR
        std::size_t seed = std::hash<int>()(std::get<0>(k));
        seed ^= std::hash<char>()(std::get<1>(k)) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
        return seed ^ (std::hash<char>()(std::get<2>(k)) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2));
    }
};

// define the comparison operator for this tuple
struct KeyEqual : public std::binary_function<MyTuple, MyTuple, bool> {
    bool operator()(const MyTuple& v0, const MyTuple& v1) const {
        return (std::get<0>(v0) == std::get<0>(v1) && std::get<1>(v0) == std::get<1>(v1) &&
                std::get<2>(v0) == std::get<2>(v1));
    }
};

typedef unordered_map<MyTuple, int, KeyHash, KeyEqual> MyMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::integer_sequence` can help:

```
struct hash_tuple {
    template <std::size_t...Index>
    size_t recursive_hash(const auto &x) const{
        return (boost::get<Index>(x) ^ ... );
    }

    template <template <typename> class Ts,typename...Args>
    size_t operator()(const Ts<Args...>& x) const{
        return recursive_hash<std::make_integer_sequence<int,sizeof...(Args)>>(x);
    }
};

using Map = std::unordered_map<Key, int, hash_tuple>;
```

This code is universal for all tuples to be uses as keys.

Comment: Note, this code requires boost::