# Variadic template pack as a key for std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, unordered-map

Is there a way to use a variadic template as a Key template parameter in `std::unordered_map`?

I tried to do it in this way:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
class Wrapper {
public:
    // some staff
private:
    unordered_map<Args, T> hashmap;

};
```

But got this error:

> Error C3520   'Args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by using a variadic template as a key? The key has to be a type, you can instantiate objects of. You can't instantiate an object whose type is a variadic pack. The closest thing is a tuple. Do you want an unordered_map with a tuple as the key?

Comment: What about `std::tuple`?

Comment: If tuple keys are what you want, it takes a little (not too much) work to use them as keys in hash maps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834838/using-tuple-in-unordered-map.

Comment: `unordered_map<T, tuple<Args...>> hashmap;`

Comment: Do you want `std::unordered_map<std::tuple<Args...>, T>` or `std::tuple<std::unordered_map<Args, T>...>` or something else ?

Comment: @Jarod42, I want the first one.

Comment: The solution with tuple that @NirFriedman suggested works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use a variadic template as a Key template parameter in std::unordered_map?

No, as far I know: `std::unordered_map` require a single key type and a single value type.

But if your intention is to have a `hashmap`, in the `Wrapper` class, for every type in `Args...`, and if the `Args...` types are all different, you can obtain it through another inheritance and another level of wrapping

```
template <typename K, typename V>
struct wrpH
 { std::unordered_map<K, V> hashmap; };

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
class Wrapper : public wrpH<Args, T>...
 { };
```

The problem of this solution is that you have more `hashmap` in the same `class` and to access they you have to explicit the corresponding base `struct`; something as follows

```
w.wrpH<Args, T>::hashmap[argsValue] = tValue;
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename K, typename V>
struct wrpH
 { std::unordered_map<K, V> hashmap; };

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
class Wrapper : public wrpH<Args, T>...
 { };

int main()
 {
   Wrapper<int, int, long, long long>  w;

   w.wrpH<long, int>::hashmap[1L] = 2;

   std::cout << w.wrpH<int, int>::hashmap.size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << w.wrpH<long, int>::hashmap.size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << w.wrpH<long long, int>::hashmap.size() << std::endl;
 }
```

If, on the contrary, you need a single `hashmap` with a key that is a combination of all `Args...` types, you can use, as key type, a class that receive a variadic list of types as template paramenters. As suggested in comments, `std::tuple` is the obvious choice

```
std::unordered_map<std::tuple<Args...>, T> hashmap;
```

This works also if some types in `Args...` coincide.

Comment: I needed a single `hashmap` with a key that is a combination of all `Args...` types. So the solution with `tuple` works for me. Thanks!